# string format padding in gridview Excel export

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, vb.net

I have a gridview

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvExportList" AutoGenerateColumns="false" AllowPaging="false" AllowSorting="false" runat="server" HeaderStyle-BackColor="LightGray">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" HeaderText="ID #" DataFormatString="&nbsp;{0}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Date" HeaderText="Date" DataFormatString="{0:MM/dd/yyyy}" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Text" HeaderText="Text" />
</Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

and a DataTable dtExportList (this is how the excel looks like now)

```
      ID       |      Date      |                Text                
-------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        |   10/9/2015    | Phone 10/09/2015 Called for assistance Wafa Dev Email
               |                | 10/09/2015 Needed Infos Monis Nasr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2        |   11/9/2015    | Phone 11/09/2015 Visit Mark Jay
```

adding the `XLS` extension to the HTML file

```
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;                
        filename=HWI_Tickets" & DateTime.Now.ToString("MMddyyy") & ".xls")
        Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel"
        Response.Charset = ""

        Dim tw As New System.IO.StringWriter
        Dim hw As New System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter(tw)
        Dim dtExportList As New DataTable

        dtExportList = Session("dtExportList")
        gvExportList.DataSource = dtExportList
        gvExportList.DataBind()

        gvExportList.RenderControl(hw)
        Response.Write(tw.ToString())
```

I want the `Text` column in excel/gridview to look like this:

```
      ID       |      Date      |                Text                
-------------------------------------------------------------------
      1        |   10/9/2015    | Phone 10/09/2015 Called for assistance  Wafa Dev
               |                | Email 10/09/2015 Needed Infos           Monis Nasr
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      2        |   11/9/2015    | Phone 11/09/2015 Visit                  Mark Jay
```

Comment: ***How is it currently looking*** when exported to Excel?

Comment: @Zaggler Just as the dattable looks like

Comment: `gvExportList is exported as an excel` no, it's not. You have an HTML file being served up with an XLS extension. That's not a good idea. It's better to generate an actual XLSX file using a library such as EPPlus, NPOI, or Open Office SDK. Then you get tight control over the resulting file.

Comment: I take it the fields are probably not stored in separate columns, which then you would have to parse that data out...

Comment: @mason this is an existing application. I don't get to decide the extension of the file.